# Display loading animation when swiper initializes?

Tags: swiper.js

I have a question about Swiper and how to display a loading animation in a responsive environment.

It's Swiper Version: 3.4.2.

#### What I did

Hi, I have set the .swiper-container to

```
{ width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

because the site is responsive. 
Otherwhise I use the standard swiper.min.css and swiper.min.js with these settings:

```
autoheight: true,
grabCursor: true,
slidesPerView: 1,
autoHeight: true,
keyboardControl: true,
paginationType: 'fraction',
pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
```

#### Expected Behavior

I would like to have the container set to the height of the first image and have a loading animation displayed in the middle of the container until the images are loaded.

#### Actual Behavior

The swiper-container is only the height of the arrows. Then next thing you see is the cropped first image (the size of the container which is the size of the arrows), and only after that, the container is set to the size of the first image.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Lazy Loading](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#lazy)?

The slideshow(/browser) will be unable to determine your slides height until the images have loaded, so you may have to manually determine the height of the image on the first slide and initialize the container with that.

See the [Images Lazy Loading demo](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/30-lazy-load-images.html).